Can I execute a JUnit5 with Restassured test after a certain time period?
I have the next integration test, in which I am using Restassured to call one of my endpoints in my Quarkus application. The endpoint calls an external service (outside of my Quarkus application) that returns a response needed to complete the flow. However, as soon as the call is made from the test below, a time frame (cooldown time) must be passed before I can call it again.
    @Test
    void testInitiateFlow() {
        given()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(createBody())
                .when()
                .post("/request")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(200)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body("response", containsString("Flow executed successfully"))
                .body("errorCode", nullValue())
                .body("errorDescription", nullValue());
    }

This means that the first time I execute my test, it passes as expected. But if I execute it again before the time frame passes, it will fail because of the external service that my Quarkus application is dependent from.
So my question is the following: Is there any JUnit 5 or other mechanism that could disable my test from being executed before the time frame passes?
Based on the documentation of the external service, the time frame is approximately five minutes that I need to wait before I execute the test again with the same request input.
To make things even worse, both of the responses (successful and unsuccessful) that come from the external service are 200 but with different response bodies.

I'm not aware of any built-in functionality in JUnit to do this.
You could add a sleep to the test, but that might be overkill - it will sleep every time you run the test, and waste a lot of time.
Another approach could be to persist the last time the test was run, and then check it in the following run, and bail out if not enough time had passed:
private static final Path TIMESTAMP_FILE_PATH = 
    Paths.get("/path/to/some/file");
private static final long WAIT_PERIOD = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes

@Test
void testInitiateFlow() {
    long lastTime = 0;
    // Check the last run
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(TIMESTAMP_FILE_PATH)) {
        lastTime = sc.nextLong();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.debug("Can't read file, it probably doesn't exist yet");
    }

    // Update the file with the current timestamp, 
    // so it's updated even if the test failed
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        Files.writeString(TIMESTAMP_FILE_PATH, String.valueOf(currTime));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Can't write to file, should be handled somehow");
    }

    Assumptions.assumeTrue
        (currTime - lastTime >= WAIT_PERIOD, 
         "Didn't have a long enough wait period, aborting the test");

    // do the test


You could do it many ways.
For example, you can mock the external service with Wiremock, then you can run it as many times as you want without any restrictions.
Another way is by making use of Awaitility, you can do something like this:
with().pollInterval(5000)
.await()
.atMost(10, SECONDS)
.until(() -> mySeviceReturnsOk());

This will first call your service and if it returns anything else than 200, it will wait 5s and try it again. And if the test keeps failing after 10s, then the test will stop and automatically fail.

The test I provided is integration test, I am calling the real external service thus I cannot use Wiremock. Just to better clarify, if I execute the test once it passes. But if try to execute it immediately upon the first execution it will fail. This happens because the external service has a cooldown time before you make the call again. Now for the Awaitility, this is something I have to check since both of the responses of the external service are 200 (yeah, this weird but it is what it is!!!).
